# How can I send a simple GET to a URL and see response back in Lambda?

Tags: amazon-web-services, get, aws-lambda

Im trying to send a simple GET request to a URL and get the response back.
I found below code that works but it only display Success but I would like to see the response. Something like this using curl:

curl -X GET http://www.some.url.com

```
    const http = require('http');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
            path: '/posts/1/',
            port: 80,
            method: 'GET'
        };
        const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
          resolve('Success');
        });
        req.on('error', (e) => {
          reject(e.message);
        });
        // send the request
        req.write('');
        req.end();
    });
};
```

Comment: Where would you like to "see the response" ? 
Are you using the AWS console to test your function?

Comment: Yes I am, I would like to see it in the "Execution Results" window below the code. At the moment I can only see Response: null I know it's success because if I enter a wrong URL it shows an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your Node.JS application, AWS Cloudwatch log the console information for Lambda function. 
You can use console.log() with a sample request like so

```
    const http = require('http');
exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const options = {
            host: 'jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
            path: '/posts/1/',
            port: 80,
            method: 'GET'
        };
        const req = http.request(options, (res) => {
          let data = '';

          // A chunk of data has been recieved.
          res.on('data', (chunk) => {
            data += chunk;
          });

          // The whole response has been received. Print out the result.
          res.on('end', () => {
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
            });

        });
        req.write('');
        req.end();
    });
};
```

The output would show, for example:

```
Function Logs:
START RequestId: ... Version: $LATEST
2019-05-08T10:35:11.650Z    ... { userId: 1,
  id: 1,
  title: 'sunt aut facere repellat provident occaecati excepturi optio reprehenderit',
  body: 'quia et suscipit\nsuscipit recusandae consequuntur expedita et cum\nreprehenderit molestiae ut ut quas totam\nnostrum rerum est autem sunt rem eveniet architecto' }
END RequestId: ...
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you for this. Sorry I'm not a developer but just trying to make this work. I run my original code with jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1/ url but if I check the CloudWatch in my console I only get StartRequest, EndRequest and how long the code run but no response. Is my code wrong?

Comment: I updated the full snippet. It should work. The code is intended for Node.Js 8.10 environment

Answer (score 1):

There is this nice [post](https://medium.com/clog/ssh-ing-into-your-aws-lambda-functions-c940cebf7646) which comments on how to SSH to an AWS Lambda and it uses a `httpbin` service to achieve that.

[httpbin.org](https:///httpbin.org) service may help you to mock and play with alternative things like sending a payload and get it back from the lambda.

The following [example](https://gist.github.com/kixorz/3b172e2fc3ce35421ee9) uses a AWS Lambda written in Node.JS to grab the current IP Address of the lambda:

```
var http = require('http');

exports.handler = function(event, context) {
    http.get('http://httpbin.org/get', function(res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function() {
            console.info(body);
            context.done(null);
        });
    }).on('error', function(e) {
        console.error(e.message);
        context.fail(null);
    });
};
```